# JQuery on click event works just one time

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-paginate

I'm having a problem with the click event on paginate bar. It run one time. Example:

I have create a paginated view using Laravel.I'm trying to do when user clicks on the paginate numbers, empty the container div and add the new `HTML` to it using `JQuery` `ajax` call. But user clicks first time on the paginate numbers it works fine, then user clicks another number then page refresh. I want to add content without refreshing.

I followed this link first answer : [How can use Laravel Pagination with Ajax `(Jquery)?][1]`

Here is my code :

**On Search Controller**

```
$vehicles = Vehicle::has('image')->orderBy('vehicles.stockNo', 'desc')->paginate(6);
if(Request::ajax())
{
    $html = View::make('templates.partials.vehicle-list',compact('vehicles'))
                ->with('page','STOCK')->render();
    return Response::json(array('html' => $html));
}
return View::make('search',compact('vehicles')) ->with('page','STOCK');
```

**On Vehicle-list Partial View**

```
@foreach($vehicles as $vehicle)
    <div class="col-md-12 search-vehicle-list-item">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="search-vehicle-title h4 col-md-12">{{ $vehicle->name . " " . $vehicle->registerYear }}</div>
            <div class="search-vehicle-short-description h6 col-md-12">
                @if(strlen($vehicle->details) > 250)
                    substr( {{ $vehicle->details }}, 0, 250)
                @else
                    {{ $vehicle->details }}
                @endif
            </div>
            <div class="search-vehicle-short-other h6 col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-4">{{ $vehicle->milage }} KM</div>
                <div class="col-md-4">{{ $vehicle->registerYear }} </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">{{ $vehicle->price }} JPY</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @endforeach

    {{ $vehicles->links() }}

    @section('scripts')
      <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function(){    
            $(".pagination a").click(function()
            {
                var myurl = $(this).attr('href');
                $.ajax({
                    url: myurl,
                    type: "get",
                    datatype: "html"
                })
                .done(function(data)
                {           
                    $("#vehicleList").empty().html(data.html);
                })
                .fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
                {
                      alert('No response from server');
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
      </script>
    @stop()
```

**On Search View**

```
    <div class="col-md-12 vehicle-listing" id="vehicleList">
        @include('templates.partials.vehicle-list')
    </div>
```

I think the problem is the click event not working after the returned data set to the div, I tried lot of things but can't find any thing. please help me out.

Comment: delegate click event to `#vehicleList` level  http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/   `$('#vehicleList').on('click', '.abc', function(){...});`

Comment: thanks for quick reply.why do i select vehicleList? I need to clear the div and add the content when user clicks on the paginate numbers?

Comment: Thanks I found the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer through Wolfs' answer. I have to use delegate click event for this situation and I used following Code and works fine..

```
@section('scripts')
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){    
    $("#vehicleList").on("click", ".pagination a",function()
    {
        var myurl = $(this).attr('href');
        $.ajax({
            url: myurl,
            type: "get",
            datatype: "html"
            //beforeSend: function()
            //{
            //  $('#ajax-loading').show();
            //}
        })
        .done(function(data)
        {           
            //$('#ajax-loading').hide();
            $("#vehicleList").empty().html(data.html);
        })
        .fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
        {
              alert('No response from server');
        });
        return false;
    });
});
  </script>
```

@stop()

Answer (score 3):

Just use this

```
$(document).on('click', '.pagination a', function(){
//your code
});
```

instaed of

```
$(".pagination a").click(function(){
//your code
});
```